# how to do searches with "google" "bing" "yahoo" using python?

Tags: python, search-engine

I've been googling for APIs to use but they all seem to be deprecated or not in use anymore.

Is there any other way to do searches and get the results?

My objective is to "recreate" [the blind search](http://blindsearch.fejus.com/) but instead of the user entering terms, I will have a set of terms predefined to search using python.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Google App Engine API?

Comment: im using ajax google search for google(but it only returns 4 results per query), pybing(which is working fairly well), but i havent found anything for yahoo yet..

Comment: [Bing has an API](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/), [Google has a new, custom search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html), and [Yahoo has the BOSS API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/).

Comment: @birryree i know im wrong but doesnt boss api cost money?

Comment: @JoeChen - it does cost money, you can see their [pricing details here](http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/search/bosspricing/details.html). But it is what you asked for. Now if you want a free Yahoo search API, that unfortunately doesn't exist anymore, as BOSS used to be free until 2010 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google are still supporting the [custom search API](http://code.google.com/intl/iw/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) [up to 100 queries/day for free]

Yahoo has the [Yahoo Search BOSS API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/).

Bing got the [Bing Developer Search API](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/), which is free

Also:

If you have some corpurus of your own, you might also want to know about [pyLucne](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/), which implements the most of search engine's functionality for you, but you will have to create your own index, unlike the existing APIs, and is is unlikely you will be able to index the web with it... so for very large scale, I'd stick with yahoo/google/bing apis.